# The global variable is not defined after Splitchunks

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks, splitchunksplugin

I'm applying the `SplitChunksPlugin` of webpack into my service.

Like,

```js
...
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all'
  }
}
```

And some issues came up. Before talking about the issues, I'll tell the minified structure of my service.

1. The web service brings serveral `script`. For example,

```html
<script crossorigin type="module" src="/js/global.[chunkhash].js"></script>
<script crossorigin type="module" src="/js/main.[chunkhash].js"></script>
```

(I'm using `menifest.json`)

2. The `global.js` is like

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

Object.assign(window, { _ });
```

3. The `main.js` is like

```js
... other codes

_.add(10, 20); // using lodash that is assigned globally in global.js
```

That's it. The real structure is more complicated. So, now is the issue.

1. When I do not use the `splitChunks` or set `splitChunks.chunks` to `async`, there is no issue. But when I set the `splitChunks.chunks` to `all`, the following issue is shown in browser.

```
_ is not defined
```

And if I type `_` in browser's console, `_` exists.

2. So, to find what happen, I insert `console.log` into `global.js` like

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

Object.assign(window, { _ });

console.log(_, window);
```

The `console.log` shows the log when `splitChunks.chunks = 'async'` but do not when `splitChunks.chunks = 'all'`.

3. Now, I try to import all vendors like

```html
/* vendors */
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendors~global.[chunkhash].js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendors~main~otherjs.[chunkhash].js"></script>
/* // vendors */
<script crossorigin type="module" src="/js/global.[chunkhash].js"></script>
<script crossorigin type="module" src="/js/main.[chunkhash].js"></script>
```

The html has above lines, but when I see the network tab in devtool, there is no vendors javascript files.

I struggle to how to apply the `splitChunksPlugin` but it is not easy... and I could not find a little clue...

It will be big help for any answer or idea ! Thanks.